# Table underscore explode for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need help!

I have an Array like this, but i dont know how to explode for an multidimensional arry:

```
array() {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["offer_id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["product_x"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["product_x_t"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["product_x_z"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["product_x_z_a"]=>
  string(3) "123"

}
```

And want it like that:

```
array(){
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["offer"]=>
  string(3) "123"
     ["id"]=>
     string(3) "123"
  ["product"]=>
  string(3) "123"
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "123"
      ["x"]=>
      string(3) "123"
          ["t"]=>
          string(3) "123"
          ["z"]=>
          string(3) "123"
              ["a"]=>
              string(3) "123"
```

But i really dont have any idea!

Comment: can you actually show the code that you want? because what you're showing is console output, not actual PHP. Your first block would be `array("id"=>1, "offer_id=>123, ...)` for instance. Also, head over to php.net and look up how to do this by searching the documentation for array functions. Read them, try them, and when you finally exhaust your options, *then* ask your question here. We love to help, but not if you've not done your own research first. We're the last resort, not the first.

Comment: Have you at least tried something? It doesn't have to work or even be close but I suspect you will be downvoted into oblivion if you don't post it.

Comment: what should be stored in newArray['product'] ? from you sample it should be string and array at the same time

Comment: Use `foreach()`, `explode` the key, make a recursive function that unshifts items from that key array and sets them in an array passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you cannot do that. Value cannot be an string and an array at the same time.

```
$value['product']['x'] = "123";
$value['product']['x'] = array('t'=>'some_value', 'z' => 'some_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it... actually its not recursive but there won't be that much cases i think...

```
function plode($val) {
    $arr = array();
        foreach($val as $key => $valval) {
            $po = explode("_", $key);
            $co = count($po);

            switch($co){
                case 1:
                    $arr[$key] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]][$po[6]] = $valval;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return $arr;

}
```

result of an aray like array("values_sale_rent_x_y_z_j" => 100, ...)

```
array(8) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["offer"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  ["product"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  ["selected"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["active"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["amount"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["payments"]=>
  string(4) "sale"
  ["values"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["rent"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["min"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["discount"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["default"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Final:

```
function plode($val, $bool = false, $deli='_') {
        $arr = array();
        foreach($val as $key => $valval) {
            $po = explode($deli, $key);
            $co = count($po);

            switch($co){
                case 1:
                    $arr[$key] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]][$po[6]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]][$po[6]][$po[7]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]][$po[6]][$po[7]][$po[8]] = $valval;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    $arr[$po[0]][$po[1]][$po[2]][$po[3]][$po[4]][$po[5]][$po[6]][$po[7]][$po[8]][$po[9]] = $valval;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if($bool) return json_decode(json_encode($arr));
        else return $arr;


     }
```